# Qt's sharing content issue on Android 10

Tags: android, qt

I have been using this piece of code to share stuff on my Qt-Android app. It works perfectly to share videos and images on any version of Android lower than 10. My problem specifically, it's that the social media panel (for sharing) is not showing up when I called it, for Android 10. In fact, I don't get any error message in the console.

```
    String target = "/real/path/to/file/mp4";
    Uri fileUri;
    File mediaFile = new File(target);
    if (mediaFile.exists())
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    String mimeType = "video/mp4";

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    sendIntent.setType(mimeType);
 
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(QtNative.activity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            String msg = "Creating social media chooser...";
            Log.i(TAG, msg);
            appendLog(msg);
        }
        QtNative.activity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title));
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) {
            String msg = "Fatal Error: Intent not resolved!";
            Log.e(TAG, msg);
            appendLog(msg);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The specific line where the social media should pop up is this:

```
QtNative.activity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title));
```

Any suggestion/workaround to fix this issue in Android 10?

PS: I already added this parameter **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** into the **AndroidManifest.xml** config file with no results.

Comment: `fileUri` please start your code definng this uri as we have no idea what and how you share. Mime type also unclear.

Comment: `that the social media panel (for sharing)` what would that be?